# Ignore PHP warning for end() function if NULL value is given

Tags: php

I have tried this:

```
try {
    $date_Firma[4] = end($date_Firma_Raw["data"]["company"]["financialData"])["turnover"];
} catch (Exception $ignored_Exception) {
    unset($ignored_Exception);
} finally {
    if ( empty($date_Firma[4]) ) {
        $date_Firma[4] = "-";
    }
}
```

For some companies, the turnover is an empty value in the array (in particular, newer companies that haven't submitted their financial year yet).

I tried to catch the PHP Warning through a try catch method and ignore it, then set the corresponding array `$date_Firma[4]` value to `"-"` however I still get the PHP Warning.

Is there something I am missing?

Update: The error: `end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Comment: You cannot try-catch warnings, _they are not exceptions_. Rather than trying to hide it, you should _fix_ your bug. If this value can be empty, __check__ for that before using it.

Comment: I can't check for it because the values are stored in the last value of the nested array. Therefore I need to get the end() value of the parent array before getting the desired values (turnover), etc. In other words, I don't know if turnover is empty till I get the last value of the financialData array.

Comment: What is the warning message?

Comment: So this means `$date_Firma_Raw["data"]["company"]["financialData"]` ends up being `null`, so check for that?

Comment: Are you saying that `$date_Firma_Raw["data"]["company"]["financialData"]` always exists and is always an array, but sometimes that array is empty? If that's the case, just use the null coalesce operator: `end($date_Firma_Raw["data"]["company"]["financialData"])["turnover"] ?? null`

Comment: @Alex Howansky perfect! That was it.